# Compile fails for [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

This program (which is supposed to implement a linked list) terminates when I run it, saying that id returned 1 exit status.
I think the problem is with linking. Am I doing it wrong or am I missing something?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>   

struct link{
    int data;
    struct link *next;
};




struct link** create(int value, struct link** head);
void print(struct link** head);  



struct link** create(int value,struct link** head)
{
    struct link* newnode = (struct link*) malloc(sizeof(struct link));
    struct link* temp=*head;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        newnode->data=value;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        *head=newnode;
    }
    else{

        while((temp->next)!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }

        newnode->data=value;
        temp->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=NULL;
    }

    print(head);
    return head;
}




void print(struct link** head)
{
    struct link* temp=*head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d------>",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}




int main()
{
    struct link** head=NULL;
    int choice,value;

    do{
        printf("the no. wanted to enter into the list:");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        create(value,head);

        printf("want to enter more press y or Y");

        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }while(choice=='y' || choice=='Y');

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: By Odin! Please format your code and use some spacing between functions, at least.

Comment: gg=G , aaaah... Indented:  http://codepad.org/2lrH2nkC

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it "Here's a pile of code.  What is wrong?"

Comment: @abelenky: not just a pile of code, but also a pile of code that cannot be compiled out-of-the box on anything but a Windows/DOS system...

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking I hadn't seen that _conio_ sucka in quite a while. I wanna say it was on a 80386 running DOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

at main

```
struct link *head=NULL;

char choice;

create(value, &head);
```

at create

```
if(*head==NULL) // or if(temp==NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?

```
while(choice=='y' or choice=='Y');
                  ^^
```

Below is correct:

```
while(choice=='y' || choice=='Y');
                  ^^
```

Note: `or` can be used in C++ (as noted by: abelenky)

Comment: C allows you to make up your own syntax, right? ;-)  Anyway... could be `#define or ||`.

Comment: `or` is a valid (but seldom used) keyword in C++ only.  It is not valid in C.

Comment: I have made the changes u suggested but its still showing same....that an undefined refrene to '_gxx_personality_seho'

Comment: @abelenky `#include <iso646.h>`